# list of options to be used in trans_primitives and agg_primitives

Tags: feature-engineering, featuretools

I am looking for the complete list of options to be used in trans_primitives and agg_primitives. For instance, my data is not time series and for new features, I would like to try mathematical functions (add, multiply, divide,...) to create new features.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a list of all the available primitives in the [Featuretools API Documentation](https://docs.featuretools.com/en/stable/api_reference.html#feature-primitives) or by visiting [primitives.featurelabs.com](https://primitives.featurelabs.com).